# Textarea bug eats my webpage on Windows Phone 8?

Tags: html, windows-phone-8

I have come over a very strange issue and I really have no clue what's going on. Is this a bug, or am I missing something in my code?

Basically what I have is a page with text and a textarea and it works fine in FireFox, Chrome and on my iPhone. But in IE on Windows Phone 8 the textarea seems to eat up the whole rest of the page. Below you can see what it looks like on the iPhone and how it *should* look like.

[image: iPhone]

Text, followed by an empty text area, followed by more text. Below you can see what I get on the WP8.

[image: Windows Phone 8]

Here the textarea is no longer empty, but instead it seems to contain the closing tag of the element that is wrapping the textarea and all HTML following it. The rest of the page is blank. Everything seems to be inside that text area.

Seriously, what's going on here? I'm using XHTML 5, so if there was a missing or unmatched end tag the whole page would have crashed. I have tried to remove all styling from the textarea element as well, but same issue. Any ideas?

---

Some of the HTML around the element:

```
  <body>
    <article class="day">
        <h1>Romersk lov</h1>
        <div class="exercise">
            <p><span class="action">Les</span> <a class="ref" href="http://www.bibel.no/Nettbibelen?parse=Luk+2%2C1%E2%80%935">Luk 2:1–5</a>. Hva kan vi lære av den måten folket forholdt seg til det politiske miljøet?</p>
            <textarea/>
        </div>
        <p>Siden republikkens første ...
    </article>
  </body>
```

---

**Update:** Seems to only happen when the textarea is empty on load... *confused*

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest this might be caused by your use a self-closing tag for the `<textarea>` it isn't a void element, it *can*, and is intended to, have contents. Instead of self-closing, try using the more appropriate:

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

This is, however, purely a guess.

Comment: Interesting. That could be. The problem is that I'm not the one closing it. The XSLT engine is :p